# SAS: Comparing large column in one table to multiple columns in separate table

Tags: arrays, string, loops, sas

I have a table with approximately 15000 string values in one column that I would like to compare with several columns in a separate table.

Here is an example of table 1 (column has about 15000 values:

```
List1
AA567
AA698
...
ZZ789
```

This is an example of table 2 (each column has approximately 150 entries):

```
Column1   Column2  Column3   ...   Column15
AA467     AA567    AA899           AA111
...       ...      ...             ...
ZZ345     ZZ567    ZZ711           ZZ789
```

If the entry in List1 matches any of the entries in Column1 through Column15, I would like to return a '1' or some indication there was a match. 
I figured I could use the coalesce function to combine across the columns in table 2, but I am not sure how I could compare with a separate table that has several thousand entries.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention if you want one flag or one for each entry in LIST.  This should give you some ideas to work with.

```
data list1;
   input target :$5.;
   cards;
AA567
AA698
ZZ789
;;;;
   run;

data column;
   input (Column1-Column3  Column15)(:$5.);
   cards;
AA467     AA567    AA899           AA111
ZZ345     ZZ567    ZZ711           ZZ789
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
data flag;
   if _n_ eq 1 then do;
      array list[3] $5 _temporary_;
      do i=1 to dim(list) while(not eof);
         set list1 end=eof;
         list[i] = target;
         end;
      end;
   flag = 0;
   set column;
   array column[*] column:;
   do i = 1 to dim(list);
      flag + list[i] in column;
      end;
   drop i target;
   run;

proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: A more performant step would have flag evaluation loop `do i = 1 to dim(list) UNTIL (FLAG);`

Comment: @Richard Yes indeed.  My method counts the matches.  I don't no understand exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: Agreed. He may next want 15,000 binary variables for logistic regression !  BTW `<variable> IN <array>` is pretty darn fast. I wonder how SAS implements it internally.

Comment: Do you know anyone at SI who could comment on how IN <Array> is implemented?

Comment: I should have been more specific with my question. I would like to check all 15,000+ entries to see if they match with each row in Table 2. After running this code it looks like it just checks the first entry of List1 only.

Comment: @statsguyz why do you think that?  What did you run and what did you expect.  As I said I do not know, because you did not say, exactly what variable(s) and values you want to create from the search.